# jpql select returns null in eclipselink

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, jpa, eclipselink

I have a very simple statement that bothers me and returns null eventhough the record is well saved in the database !!

I have an "administrateur" and "exploitant" entities that inherit "Utilisateur" entity (user in english xd) as follows :

======================  **entity administrateur**  ===============

```
    @Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
@Table(name="ADMINISTRATEUR")
public class Administrateur extends Utilisateur{

    public Administrateur(){

    }
}
```

======================  **entity utilisateur**  ===============

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_UTILISATEUR")
@Table(name="UTILISATEUR")
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="utilisateur_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="utilisateur_seq_gen", sequenceName="UTILISATEUR_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    protected Long id_utilisateur;
    @Column(name="NOM")
    protected String nom;
    @Column(name="PRENOM")
    protected String prenom;

    @Column(name="LOGIN")
    protected String login;
    @Column(name="MOT_PASSE_UTILISATEUR")
    protected String mot_passe_utilisateur;
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    protected String email;
```

======================  **entity explotant**  ===============

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("E")
@Table(name="EXPLOITANT")
public class Exploitant extends Utilisateur{

    @Column(name="ROLE")
    private String role;
public Exploitant(){

    }
}
```

I use this request to retrieve a user :

```
    public Utilisateur getUserTest(){
    EntityManager em=new JPAContainerFactory().createEntityManagerForPersistenceUnit("addressbook");
    em.getTransaction().begin();

TypedQuery<Utilisateur> query_user = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur AS u WHERE u.id_utilisateur=1", Utilisateur.class);
    em.getTransaction().commit();   

    return query_user.getSingleResult();
}
```

Then i call it here :

```
final Utilisateur us=saut.getUserTest();
```

This is a simple request that doesn't work, the same is for this request :

```
    public Utilisateur getUserFromMail(String email){
    EntityManager em=new JPAContainerFactory().createEntityManagerForPersistenceUnit("addressbook");
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    TypedQuery<Utilisateur> query_user = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur AS u WHERE u.email= :email", Utilisateur.class);
    query_user.setParameter("email", email);
    em.getTransaction().commit();   

    return query_user.getSingleResult();
}
```

Then i call it from here :

```
Utilisateur user=saut.getUserFromMail(emailString);
//user.setMot_passe_utilisateur(String.valueOf(pswd));
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.merge(user);
em.flush();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

It says that getsingle result doesn't retrieve any result !!

In the database i'm 100% that the result exists :

[image]

I can't figure out the problem, can anyone help with a pertinent answer.

Thanks.

**Edit**

I got log gives the following error : 
[image]

Sauthentifier.java:150 = refer to :`return query_user.getSingleResult();`

=====
Creer_encaissement.java:332= refer to `final Utilisateur us=saut.getUserTest();`

The request in the database return the appropriate result.
Also i got this logout :

[image]

Comment: Why is your query `SELECT u FROM Utilisateur AS u` ? Is there a field named `u`? Did you mean `u.*` ?

Comment: @Brian this is how it's done in jpql i believe, u can check :

https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_select

or : https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL

Comment: the 'as' is optional and commonly omitted; "SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u" is also valid.  Can you set EclipseLink to log the generated SQL and post it?  See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging for how.  Try executing the query in the database directly and see the results.  I don't believe you need to wrap simple select queries within a transaction - as long as it is not a JTA datasource, the query doesn't need a transaction, and if it is a JTA datasource, you can't start one using em.getTransaction().begin(); anyway.

Comment: @Chris i've added the logout, but i don't undrestand why this is returning null, because i have other queries with exactly the same syntax and they don't return null. For the  i didn't get your proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common reasons for this issue:

1. You might be checking the database with a different user/schema
   from the application
2. You have the full data that is needed to build your entity.  In this case, your Utilisateur should have a row in both the "UTILISATEUR" and "ADMINISTRATEUR" tables, and the ADMINISTRATEUR table needs an ID= 1 and Type=A.  Both have to be there for a Utilisateur instance to exist.

If that does not work, try persisting a Utilisateur and then reading that same instance back in.

Comment: I was adding records from a script :  INSERT INTO UTILISATEUR VALUES (1, 'ADMINISTRATEUR', 'am_dehimi@esi.dz', 'admin', 'admin', 'Farid', 'Farid'); and this doesn't insert into the administrateur table. Then i added :  INSERT INTO ADMINISTRATEUR(ID_UTILISATEUR) VALUES (1); 

Insertion via entities (java code) is better (jpa deal with the constraints and inheritance) rather than sql where i have to add manually to all tables. Thanks @Chris.

Comment: how can i get for example administrateur.nom knowing that "nom" is an attribute of utilisateur (administrateur extends utilisateur) in sql. am i obliged to use join via the ID_Utilisateur ? Thanks

Comment: I thought you are using JPA, which allows you to query over any entity attribute and will handle the joins in SQL for you.  If using native SQL queries, yes, you must handle joins to the tables you need to include in your select or where clause yourself.

Comment: no no i'm using jpa, the problem is that i have to join three to four tables which is complicated because i have many inheritances, i'm thinking of creating a view for that. Do you think that a view with table annotation will be bettre than a jpql statement (typed query) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping is OK, your code is OK.
What is missing is an entry in the `ADMINISTRATEUR` table for the `id_utilisateur==1`;

Comment: You were right, the record was in the table Utilisateur but not in the table Administrateur. Thanks mate.